# React Redux how to use one reducer for two similar actions in two different components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a page with two "smart" components:

- PageChildrenTabs
- StaticPage

I have an action function:

```
function fetchPage(slug) {
     return {
         type: 'FETCH_PAGE',
         payload: axios.get(PAGE_ENDPOINT + slug);
     }
}
```

And I have a reducer:

```
export function pageReducer(state={
    pending: false,
    payload: {data: {}},
    error: null
}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCH_PAGE_PENDING": {
            return {...state, pending: true, payload: {data: {}}, error: null};
        }
        case "FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED": {
            return {...state, pending: false, payload: action.payload, error: null};
        }
        case "FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED": {
            return {...state, pending: false, payload: {data: {}}, error: action.payload};
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

PageChildrenTabs calls `this.props.fetchPage('about');`, while StaticPage calls `this.props.fetchPage('about/history');`. Both of these functions happen at the same time because they are both rendered under a parent container component.

Now, here is my problem. Only data for one action response is shown in both components. both  I understand that it might be because one removes the other. What is the proper way to achieve what I want to achieve? How can I load the same action twice in two separate components at the same time using a single reducer?

EDIT: Clarified what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redux state stores everything in the whole app in one tree. If you need to store more than one of something you just make an array or a hash. In this case you'll probably want to store this data by slug.

Action creator:

```
function fetchPage(slug) {
     return {
         type: 'FETCH_PAGE',
         slug,
         payload: axios.get(PAGE_ENDPOINT + slug);
     }
}
```

Reducer:

```
function singlePageReducer(state={
    pending: false,
    payload: {data: {}},
    error: null
}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCH_PAGE_PENDING": {
            return {...state, pending: true, payload: {data: {}}, error: null};
        }
        case "FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED": {
            return {...state, pending: false, payload: action.payload, error: null};
        }
        case "FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED": {
            return {...state, pending: false, payload: {data: {}}, error: action.payload};
        }
    }
    return state;
}

export function pageReducer (state = {}, action) {
  if (["FETCH_PAGE_PENDING", "FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED", "FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED"].indexOf(action.type) !== -1) {
    return { ...state,  [action.slug]: singlePageReducer(state[action.slug], action) };
  }
  return state; 
}
```

You can compose multiple reducers together to make a data symphony. Look at the [todos example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/reducers/todos.js) for simple inspiration.